# Ошибка Notice: Undefined index: payment_method

Tags: php, opencart

Слегка отредактировал стандартный модуль OcStore 2.3 под себя, модуль вроде бы работает, всё считает, но выдаёт такую ошибку:

> Notice: Undefined index: payment_method in
>   public_html/catalog/model/extension/total/handling.php on line 4

В чем может быть проблема?

```
    <?php
class ModelExtensionTotalHandling extends Model {
    public function getTotal($total) {
        if ($this->session->data['payment_method']['code'] == 'bank_transfer') { $status = false; } else {
        $sub_total = $this->cart->getSubTotal();

        if (($sub_total > $this->config->get('handling_total')) && ($sub_total > 0)) {
            $this->load->language('extension/total/handling');

            $total['totals'][] = array(
                'code'       => 'handling',
                'title'      => $this->language->get('text_handling'),
                'value'      => $total['total'] / 100 * $this->config->get('handling_fee'),
                'sort_order' => $this->config->get('handling_sort_order')
            );


            $total['total'] = $total['total'] / 100 * $this->config->get('handling_fee');
        }
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему в данных сессии `$this->session->data` нет ключа **payment_method**

По этому куску кода непонятно, должен ли он быть там и почему не попадает